# How can I update the Facebook SDK within nativescript-plugin-firebase?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue, nativescript-plugin

Facebook is giving me a warning that my SDK is out of date but I'm using `nativescript-plugin-firebase`.

Can I just manually update the sdk versions in

`node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/android/include.gradle` and `node_modules/nativescript-plugin-firebase/platforms/ios/Podfile` respectively?

Comment: You may do that, but you will have to update the file every time when you re-install node modules Or you could write a hook that will do it every time automatically. Also you might want to make sure whether the plugin code is compatible to version you are upgrading to.

Comment: @Manoj the build failed on the Facebook sdk 5.0 (which was kind of expected honestly). Facebook is now insisting that this is why our app is hanging for them, even though we cannot reproduce the issue. Any thoughts on what to do?

Comment: As you might already know Firebase is a community plugin, developed and maintained by EddyVerbruggen. You may post an issue at Github repo requesting for an update on the Facebook SDK. Eddy is a busy man, but I guess he might also be available for paid engagements if this is very crucial. There is enterprise support from Progress, platform experts you may able to reach out to, on Slack. With the minimal info you have shared about the SDK issue, I doubt you may able to find a solution here.

Comment: @Manoj I know he's extremely busy and there was already an open issue to update to (I believe) 4.3.7  with a 'help wanted' tag so I didn't want to bother him. I'd love to help but that's above my abilities. The sdk turned out to not be issue even though Facebook insisted it was and they lifted the restriction so I guess I'll call that good enough for now.